# I want to print a message only once if the input field is blank and user hits enter with blank input. where am I going wrong

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => { //create new invitee name
let text = input.value; //collect text value from input field
let counter = 0;
if (text != "") {
    createLI(text); //executes function to add new invitee. 
} else {. /*if text field is blank error message to be printed only once regardless on multiple entries with blank input*/

    const errorText = document.getElementById('enterName');
    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.textContent = "please enter your full name";
    label.setAttribute("style", "color: red");
    if (counter == 0) {
        errorText.appendChild(label);
        counter += 1;
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with `let counter = 0;`

Declare it outside of the event listener callback. Like

```
 let counter = 0;
 form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => { //create new invitee name
  let text = input.value; //collect text value from input field
   ....
```

What's wrong with your code is that everytime event fires, it set `counter` to `0` again and you the child appended.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `counter` outside the function, otherwise it's reset every single time the user submits the form.

```
let counter = 0;
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => { /* Your awesome eventhandler */ });
```

This happens because JavaScript deletes your variable once the function's ended, and it redeclares it when the event is fired again. So it actually *reinitializes* the `counter`.

**PROTIP**: Use a `bool` instead of an `int`, so you can just

```
if (messageShowed) { /* Insert some code */ }
```